# find leftover days in a year in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need help to find out how many days are left out in a year

EG. consider year 2013
In PHP the week number starts from 1-52 
and the last days 30dec and 31dec have week number as 1

i want to find out how many such days are there in a year . 
in 2013 , there are 2 such dyas 
in 2012 there is 1 such day

Comment: Check which day is 31 december and then get the difference to monday.

Comment: hey nice one , thanks Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Check which day is 31 december and then get the difference the first day of the week.
And you must also count the monday.

```
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp);
```

$dw will be 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday. So left over days are only present when you get a result 0 or larger.

Sollution(not tested):

```
       $dw = date( "w", $timestamp);


    if ($dw > 0){
      echo $dw;
    }
else {
echo "no left over"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way where the code speaks mostly for itself:

```
<?php

$lastSunday = new DateTime('last Sunday of December 2013');
$lastDay    = new DateTime('last day of December 2013');

// $leftovers will be of type DateInterval
$leftovers  = $lastSunday->diff($lastDay);

echo $leftovers->d . ' leftover days';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the DateTime object.

```
$Date = new DateTime('31-12-2013');

$count = 0;
while($Date->format('W') == 1) {
    $count++;
    $Date->modify('-1 day');
}

echo $count;
```

Comment: @user3148470 Well, maybe because there is not any? From 2015 till 2018 there is not a day that is in the first week at the end of the year.

Comment: @GertB. Why? You can always assume that the last date of the year is 31-12, so what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Benz I'm not saying this does not work. But you create a variable $date that contains a hardcoded date. if say a co-worker writes a new part of code and sees a $date variable, he could use it, causing bugs. its better to edit say use another variable name, like $endYearDate, and maybe softcode the year

Comment: @GertB. I agree that it is a risk when using this in your company's repository. But we are on stackoverflow, a community where we help people using examples(!). What would be your solution in this case? Adding another variable with a date as string?

Comment: @Benz i added an answer, and yes we are on stack overflow, Where we help people with examples, but also improve answers given. When I say hardcoding dates is bad practice, i'm not saying that to offend you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45347/discussion-between-benz-and-gert-b)